# How to type enum values mapped from key correctly

Tags: typescript, enums

I've tried to make these two functions to get the keys and values of enums. They seem to work, and I've figured out *most* of the typing, just one error left, that I was hoping someone wiser than I in TypeScript could help out with...

```js
const isInteger = /^\d+$/;

export const enumKeys = <T>(enumObj: T): string[] => {
  return Object.keys(enumObj).filter(k => !isInteger.test(k));
};

export const enumValues = <T>(enumObj: T): T[keyof T][] => {
  return enumKeys(enumObj).map(k => enumObj[k]);
};
```

The issue is the `enumObj[k]`, which gives this type error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because type '{}' has no index signature. ts(7017)

I know I could just ignore the warning, but I want to learn, and I don't understand why/what exactly is implicitly `any` here, and how to correctly type it to not be that.

---

**Solution, based on accepted answer**

```js
const isInteger = /^\d+$/;

export const enumKeys = <T>(enumObj: T): (keyof T)[] => {
  return Object.keys(enumObj)
    .filter(k => !isInteger.test(k))
    .map(k => k as keyof T);
};

export const enumValues = <T>(enumObj: T): T[keyof T][] => {
  return enumKeys(enumObj).map(k => enumObj[k]);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of TS have the following error

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'unknown'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'unknown'.ts(7053)
```

The type parameter `T` has no type constraint so by default its constraint is (`unknown` or `{}` depending on the version). When you try to index with `enumObj[k]`, `k` is of type `string`, but `enumObj` does not support indexing with `string` as it has no index signature that accepts `string`.

The simple solution is to assert that `k` is indeed a key of `T`:

```
export const enumKeys = <T>(enumObj: T): string[] => {
  return Object.keys(enumObj).filter(k => !isInteger.test(k));
};

export const enumValues = <T>(enumObj: T): T[keyof T][] => {
  return enumKeys(enumObj).map(k => enumObj[k as keyof T]);
};
```

Comment: That did it! And I was able to "flip it around" as well, so the `enumKeys` doesn't cause this error elsewhere also. Added my adjusted code to my question.